# not getting expected data in array

Tags: node.js, async-await

Here's my code,I am getting the latLongData array without the Objects. How to resolve it? What could be the possible reason?

```
let latLongData = [];
async function calcLatLong() {
  let Obj = {
    loadId: locPoints.loadId,
    latLongs: []
  };
  try {
    for (let point of locPoints.loadingUnloadingPoints) {
      if (point.location) {
        Obj.latLongs.push(await getLatLong(point.location));
      }
    }
    latLongData.push(Obj);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
  return latLongData;
}
```

Even after using `for..of` instead of `forEach` loop the problem persists.

Comment: post the code where you call this function

Comment: I think this can be useful (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop/37576787) for your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Can I solve the problem using Generators? @laggingreflex

Comment: You added "Even after using `for..of` instead of `forEach` loop the problem persists.". Could you add the exact code how you used for..of? It should've worked.

Comment: Sure, @laggingreflex. I have made the relevant changes in the code.

Comment: Seems like it should work. Could you add what data are you expecting VS what are you actually getting?

Comment: I am expecting data resolved by the API that I have called and pushed into the array. It is simply that the function is returning before the data gets resolved.

Comment: for..do is very slow and taking much time. Please suggest some alternatives. @laggingreflex I will be grateful to you.

Comment: @BinayakGS There was also another suggestion `Promise.all` in the answer linked above, try that.

Comment: Both types of for loops are fine in async functions. Only functional solutions like forEach are problematic.